# Movement nudge instead of constant

Tags: unity

I am making a small game where the player is constantly moving upwards, and I am having slight problems with the movement to the sides.
The script located under works quite perfectly in itself, but my problem is that I want the balloon-player to nudge in a direction, rather than go at a constant speed. Kinda like a small punch to the side of the balloon.

[image]

How could I easily implement this? GetMouseButton or GetMouseButtonDown?
Thanks in advance. :)

```
    void Update () {

    transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

    if(Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

}
```

Comment: As in you want some push when the button is clicked once? Then you want it to slow down over time?

Comment: Yes. This will be for my android tablet, and I want simple taps on the sides to nudge the balloon in that direction. so a small acceleration as well. :)

Comment: You should use Lerp for this

Comment: Sounds like you just need to apply some force.

Comment: For what I see you are not using physics, are you? 
Without using physics you need a couple of tricks to reach your final effect:
1) reproduce a little tilting/rotating animation on your baloon sprite (rotate around z-axis) and come back to initial rotation.
2) use Vector3.Lerp to add an extra slide-movement component to your translation vector and apply over a time-window.

If you need more code just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it would be something the physics system could fairly easily handle. I'd add a `Rigidbody2D` and then you can manipulate the balloon via the `AddForce` function. Note that in order to make the balloon "rise" you can get rid of your translate and instead set `GravityScale` to something like `-0.5` and it will "fall" but up.

So I'd do something like this:

```
void Update () 
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        rigidbody2D.AddForce(-Vector2.right);
    }
    else if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Humm, this doesn't quite work. I use this script, and mess around with the Rigidbody2D components. With that script activated, any change to Gravity Scale does nothing, until I turn on Is Kinematic.

Comment: You have to turn OFF `IsKinematic` and you have to make sure you're not trying to manually change the object's position yourself.

Comment: Turning off IsKinematic makes it so the balloon continues to increase speed, to the point he flies through the "roof". The script also does nothing to move the player. I am trying to figure out why now. :)

EDIT: Just set gravity scale to 0, and now I can barely nudge the balloon to the sides. I just got to tweak the numbers, and make it not continuously add speed upwards.

Comment: If you set gravity scale to 0 and it's still going upwards - you're manually pushing it upwards somehow. If you're trying to nudge it harder left/right you need to manually create a left/right vector with a larger X value or multiply the Vector2.right by some number to increase the force.

Comment: rigidbody2D.AddForce(-Vector2.right * 50);

I ended up doing it like this. However, it feels stale, seeing as a nudge in the other direction just nulls out the first nudge, making the balloon stand still.

And no, when I set Gravity to 0, it stands still.

Comment: That sounds right. What you might be expecting is for the balloon to have more linear drag.

Comment: Yeah, it makes totally sense that the ballon reset to just going up when it has gotten a nudge -50, and then +50. Thanks for the answer, I will stop here to avoid making this a long discussion. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a Velocity/Inertia system. Create an additional vector to represent the amount of "energy" in a given direction for the object - I call mine "Velocity". Every update, apply a percentage of the velocity to the position and subtract it from the velocity. Every time you hit a button to move, add to the velocity rather than directly moving the object.

It's a bit convoluted to set up but it works quite nicely and is the way its always done afaik.